# How to programmatically retrieve the unicode char from hexademicals?

Tags: python, arrays, string, unicode, hex

**Given a list of hexadecimals that corresponds to the unicode, how to programmatically retrieve the unicode char?**

E.g. Given the list:

```
>>> l = ['9359', '935A', '935B']
```

how to achieve this list:

```
>>> u = [u'\u9359', u'\u935A', u'\u935B']
>>> u
['鍙', '鍚', '鍛']
```

I've tried this but it throws a `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> u'\u' + l[0]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\uhhhh` escapes are only valid in string literals, you can't use those to turn arbitrary hex values into characters. In other words, they are part of a larger syntax, and can't be used stand-alone.

Decode the hex value to an integer and pass it to the [`chr()` function](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr) (or, on Python 2, the [`unichr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr)):

```
[chr(int(v, 16)) for v in l]  #
```

You *could* ask Python to interpret a string containing *literal `\uhhhh` text* as a Unicode string literal with the [`unicode_escape` codec](https://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings), but feels like overkill for individual codepoints:

```
[(b'\\u' + v.encode('ascii')).decode('unicode_escape') for v in l]
```

Note the double backslash in the prefix added, and that we have to create byte strings for this to work at all.

Demo:

```
>>> l = ['9359', '935A', '935B']
>>> [chr(int(v, 16)) for v in l]
['鍙', '鍚', '鍛']
>>> [(b'\\u' + v.encode('ascii')).decode('unicode_escape') for v in l]
['鍙', '鍚', '鍛']
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @MartijnPieters!!

Comment: For those using Python 3, the function to use is `chr` instead of `unichr`.

Comment: @Guimoute: lets turn that around; for those using Python 2, the function to use is `unichr` instead of `chr` (answer updated, thanks).